# XSL Stylesheet Path with Quartz Job

Tags: java, xslt, quartz

I have an action that turns XML data into an XSL based report that is viewed on a web page. A separate action called by a user can be used to transform this report into a PDF and save it to a location.

I am looking to use the Quartz Scheduler to run and save the report as a PDF every day. I have confirmed that the Quartz Scheduler runs successfully, however when it attempts to transform the data into a PDF report is fails.

```
public byte[] render(Action action, String location) throws Exception {

    // Transform the source XML to System.out.
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {

        // configure fopFactory as desired
        FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();

        // configure foUserAgent as desired
        FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();

        // Create a transformer for the stylesheet.
        Templates templates = null;
        Transformer transformer;
        if (location != null) {
            templates = getTemplates(location);
            transformer = templates.newTransformer();
        } else {
            transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        }
        transformer.setURIResolver(getURIResolver());
        Object result = action;

        Source xmlSource = getDOMSourceForStack(result);

        // Construct fop with desired output format
        Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);
        Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
        transformer.transform(xmlSource, res);
        return out.toByteArray();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        out.close(); // ...and flush...
    }
}

protected Templates getTemplates(String path) throws TransformerException, IOException {
    
    if (path == null) {
        throw new TransformerException("Stylesheet path is null");
    }
    Templates templates = null;
    URL resource = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getResource(path);

    if (resource == null) {
        throw new TransformerException("Stylesheet " + path + " not found in resources.");
    }
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    templates = factory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(resource.openStream()));

    return templates;
}

protected Source getDOMSourceForStack(Object value)
        throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    return new DOMSource(getAdapterFactory().adaptDocument("result", value));
}

protected AdapterFactory getAdapterFactory() {
    if (adapterFactory == null) {
        adapterFactory = new AdapterFactory();
    }
    return adapterFactory;
}

protected void setAdapterFactory(AdapterFactory adapterFactory) {
    this.adapterFactory = adapterFactory;
}

protected URIResolver getURIResolver() {
         return new ServletURIResolver(
                 ServletActionContext.getServletContext());
     }
 }
```

The action parameter is the action that runs the report that will be transformed and the location parameter is the location of the XSL Stylesheet that formats the report. This action functions when called by the user, but when Quartz tries to call it on a scheduled basis it throws a NullPointerException error at the

```
    URL resource = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getResource(path);
```

line. Is there a way to get Quartz to work with this transformation action?

Answer (score 0):

Your code throws NPE because it is executed by Quartz outside of a Struts action and therefore `ServletActionContext.getServletContext()` returns null. You need to find out a different way to get hold of the `ServletContext`. The easiest would be implementing a `ServletContextListener` that would save the `ServletContext` instance in a private static field when its `contextInitialized` method is invoked. Then in your Quartz job code, you would use something like this:

> MyServletContextListener.getServletContext().getResource(path);

`getServletContext` is a static method that you will need to add to your `ServletContextListener` and it will simply return the saved `ServletContext` instance.

You need to make sure Quartz is started AFTER your `ServletContextListener's` `contextInitialized` method has been called. The easiest would be starting Quartz from the `contextInitialized` method. This ensures that when Quartz executes any of your jobs, the `ServletContext` field would be initialized and `MyServletContextListener.getServletContext()` would not return null.